# Программное заполнение EditText

Tags: java, android

Есть несколько кнопок на экране и `Edittext`. Нужно чтобы текстовое поле заполнялось по нажатию кнопок без удаления предыдущих символов (получается заполнение будто с клавиатуры)

Может кто нибудь знает решение?

Answer (score 3):

```
onClick (View v){
    //так
    edt.append("ваш текст");
    //или так
    String text = editText.getText().toString()+"ваш текст";
    editText.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я вас правильно понял вам нужно дополнять текст в `EditText`

Я рекомендую использовать следующий код.

```
edt.setText(edt.getText() + " " + "ваш текст");
```